# webapi2 Binding not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm new to webapi 2 and trying to get my api to bind to this call below.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Call:
https://blabla.azurewebsites.net/myjohndeere/authenticated/e33dd8f74c97474d86c75b00dd28ddf8?oauth_token=1539dccf-d935-4d9e-83be-e00f76cabbb9&oauth_verifier=B22dWL

```
[RoutePrefix("myjohndeere")]
public class ApiMyJohnDeereController : ApplicationController
{

    [HttpGet, Route("authenticated/{callbackId}")]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(ApiResponseModel))]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "An unknown error occurred")]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Missing FieldMappings")]
    public IHttpActionResult Authenticated(string callbackId,[FromUri]string oauth_token, [FromUri]string oauth_verifier)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: What is `ApplicationController`? Does regular API action method work or specific to OAuth action method?

Comment: a derived ApiController

Comment: Are you trying to capture `access_token`? Where did you get the above code?

Comment: I wrote it, apparently not correctly. Yes trying to get all the parameter values;

Comment: OAuth workflow doesn't seem correct. Who is your Identity Provider?

Comment: This is an unsecured call

Comment: I'm integrating with john deere, they use OAuth. This is a callback from John Deere

Comment: You might want to look at `OpenIdConnect` middleware rather than hand-rolling the security mechanism by yourself.

Comment: @Win, yes a lot of this is existing old code, going from asp.net to webapi2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the Azure API gateway was still set to use PUT rather than GET.

Answer (score 0):

First of, you missed the 'api' in the route.

Try it like this

> https://blabla.azurewebsites.net/api/myjohndeere/authenticated/e33dd8f74c97474d86c75b00dd28ddf8?oauth_token=1539dccf-d935-4d9e-83be-e00f76cabbb9&oauth_verifier=B22dWL

Then, remove the FromUri attribute from your controller method. The attribute is not needed when just reading querystring of value types.

Try it like this

```
public IHttpActionResult Authenticated(string callbackId, string oauth_token, string oauth_verifier)
```

Comment: @StackOverflowNaziHater by default, the api controllers are routed under /api/yourcontroller.. Try to remove the FromUri. They are note neaded when just reading value types from uri